# Unable to display Public DNS when using aws ec2_instance module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My EC2 instance module configuration for `us-east-1` looks as below:

```
module "ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "~> 5.2.0"
    
  for_each = toset(["one", "two", "three"])
    
  name = "instance-${each.key}"
  ami = "ami-0f34c5ae932e6f0e4"
  
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = "ec2keypair"
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0d1e7372e359bfa42"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-0ff5469ab7c53e44b"
  user_data = file("apache-install.sh")
  
  tags = {
    "Name" = "Modules-Demo"
     Terraform   = "true"
     Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

My output looks as below:

```
output "ec2_publicip" {
  description = "Public IP of an EC2 Instance"
  value = module.ec2_instance.*.public_ip
}
```

This is throwing below error:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
> on c5-outputs.tf line 8, in output "ec2_publicip":
> 8:   value = module.ec2_instance.*.public_ip
> This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".

I have gone through the documentation and `public_ip` is showing as [valid attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws/latest#output_public_ip).

Comment: Is your subnet public ? Do you have an Internet Gateway ? Does your subnet auto-attribute public IPs ? 
When your instances are created, you should check in the console if it has a public IP or not.

Comment: This is a public subnet having igw in the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the module you want it to [assign a public IP address to the instance](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/blob/master/main.tf#L41):

```
module "ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "~> 5.2.0"

  for_each = toset(["one", "two", "three"])

  name                        = "instance-${each.key}"
  ami                         = "ami-0f34c5ae932e6f0e4"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  key_name                    = "ec2keypair"
  monitoring                  = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["sg-0d1e7372e359bfa42"]
  subnet_id                   = "subnet-0ff5469ab7c53e44b"
  associate_public_ip_address = true # <---- add this line
  user_data = file("apache-install.sh")
  tags = {
    "Name" = "Modules-Demo"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Additionally, since the module is created using `for_each`, to get all of the outputs, you need to use the [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
output "ec2_publicip" {
  description = "Public IP of an EC2 Instance"
  value       = values(module.ec2_instance)[*].public_ip
}
```

Comment: Even after adding `associate_public_ip_address = true` I am still getting the same error. This is a public subnet having igw in the routes

Comment: I think you might need something like `module.ec2_instance[*].public_ip`.

Comment: Still getting same error. `│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on c5-outputs.tf line 8, in output "ec2_publicip":
│    8:   value = module.ec2_instance[*].public_ip
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".
`

Comment: Ah, it's using `for_each`, so you need `values(module.ec2_instance)[*].public_ip`.

Comment: It is working now. Can you please help me understand why this is not correct `module.ec2_instance.*.public_ip`? My understanding is that the `spat operator` loops through all the elements and print them.

Comment: Yes, it does, but through a list. When using `for_each` it creates a map of key value pairs. The values built-in function fetches all the values from a map. Since you want to fetch all the attributes of all the module instances, i.e. keys, then you need to use the `[*]`, followed by the attribute you want. You can also take a look at [this](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat#splat-expressions-with-maps).

Comment: can you please help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869629/unable-to-taint-a-particular-resource-from-the-ec2-instance-module